# Swift: Runtime error when assigning a value `[T]?` to var of type `[T?]`

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

Is there any way that I can assign an optional array of non-optional type to a variable expecting a non-optional array of optional type?

Contrived example:

```
var a: [T]?
let thing: T = T()
a = [thing]

var b: [T?] = []
if a != nil {
    b = a!
}
```

The compiler doesn't complain, but at runtime I receive `fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C` which I've deduced is from the types conflicting in the assignment `b = a!`.

Am I perhaps missing some fundamental understanding of Swift that would make attempting such an assignment silly or unnecessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optionals in Swift are in fact enumerations like:

```
enum Optional<Wrapped> {
    case None
    case Some(Wrapped)
}
```

All the operations on optionals (e.g. with `?`, or with `!`, etc) are just short-hands provided by Swift to make it easy to use and understand.

Arrays are also in fact generic structures like:

```
struct Array<Element> {
    // ...
}
```

`[]` syntax for declaration is again a (recommended by Apple) shorthand.

Now, if you look at what `[Int?]` and `[Int]?` really boil down to, you will see that they are quite different:

```
let foo = Array<Optional<Int>>()     // [Int?]
let bar: Optional<Array<Int>> = nil  // [Int]?
```

Now, in order to assign one to another you will have to provide some conversion code.  E.g. something like this:

```
let foo: [Int]? = [1, 2, 3]
var bar: [Int?] = []

bar = (foo ?? []).map() { $0 }
```

In the above code `(foo ?? [])` unwraps the optional array, providing an empty array as a substitute for `nil` case, and then `map()` function maps array of non-optionals to array of optionals (Swift automatically infers the non-optional to optional conversion for you).

Comment: Thanks! Your conversion example was exactly what I was looking for. And I learned about the ?? operator too!

Answer (score 1):

This should clear things up:

- `[T]` is syntactic sugar for `Array<T>`
- `T?` is syntactic sugar for `Optional<T>`
- `[T?]` is syntactic sugar for `Array<Optional<T>>`
- `[T]?` is syntactic sugar for `Optional<Array<T>>`

`[T]?` implies that an array **might / might not** be there. If it is, it will be an array of type `Array<T>`. If it isn't, then that's it.

I assume what you were looking for is `a ?? []` which unwraps `a`, checks whether it has a value or not, returns either the present value or a substitute `[]` (an empty array). So you either get an array with/without elements, or an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand something.
First:

[T]? == Array of T which is optional.

[T?] == Array of T? , an Array contain optional T.

Can we convert a to b when it's not nil?
Yes. You can always convert [T] to [T?] by map().
In your case, that would be

```
b = a.map(){ original -> T? in return original }
```

But if you want the reverse:

```
a = b.filter { original -> T in return original != nil }
```